# Muons produced in electromagnetic particle cascades

Tags: particle-physics

When a very high energy photon reaches the atmosphere and interacts with the air molecules, it produces an electron-positron pair due to pair production. These electron and positron still have very high energy and emit photons due to bremsstrahlung. These photons further produce electron and positron pairs and an electromagnetic shower develops.

If the particle arriving to the atmosphere is a very-high-energy proton, the process is different. When it interacts with the air molecules it produces pions that further decay into muons. Some of these pions are $\pi^0$ that decay into two photons and form the electromagnetic part of the shower. Nevertheless, muons do not decay or produce photons by bremsstrahlung, therefore they continue until they reach the ground.

My question is: why are there showers initiated by photons that contain a muon, what is the process taking place for an electron/positron cascade to produce muons? When do these muons stop, when they decay after their ~$\mu$s lifetimes or due to bremsstrahlung on the ground?

Answer (score 0):

In recent years gamma ray initiated cosmic showers have become important , because they can be detected as separate from the cosmic rays within our galaxy and used for astronomical purposes as signals from extragalactic events.

[Here is behind a pay wall](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4616/11/6/004) a calculation of the number of muons coming from high energy gamma rays:

> The muon content of gamma-ray-initiated extensive air showers is of considerable importance following the recent detection of excess showers, attributed to ultrahigh energy gamma rays from Cygnus X-3, Vela X-1 and the Crab Nebula. In two of these observations the muon content of the showers have been measured and found to be only marginally less than in cosmic-ray-initiated showers. The authors report the *result of a calculation of the expected number of muons in gamma-ray-initiated and cosmic-ray-initiated air showers using a realistic model of hadronic collisions.* The model is used to assess the feasibility of using the muon content of showers as a veto to reject cosmic-ray-initiated showers in gamma ray astronomy.

The italics mine to show that it is hadronic collisions that will end up with secondary muons that the model calculates. If you have access to a library you could get the detailed arguments.

A mechanism that has to be taken into account:[e+e- into hadrons,](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2014/hadronic-xsections/rpp2014-sigma_R_ee_plots.pdf) for example is ten times more probable as the hadronic ratio shows. The positrons from the initial gamma ray pair production have a high probability of generating hadrons  hitting an electron of an atom in the atmosphere, and hence the pi-mu-e decay . Muon decays of other particles have to be taken into account too. So a detailed model is necessary.

Here is a current [publication,](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01794)

> Muon component of extensive air showers (EAS) initiated by cosmic ray particles carries information on the primary particle identity. We show that the muon content of EAS could be measured in a broad energy range from 10-100 TeV up to ultra-high-energy cosmic ray range using wide field-of-view imaging atmospheric Cherenkov telescopes observing strongly inclined or nearly horizontal EAS from the ground of from high altitude. Cherenkov emission from muons in such EAS forms a distinct component (halo or tail) of the EAS image in the telescope camera. We show that detection of the muon signal could be used to measure composition of the cosmic ray spectrum in the energy ranges of the knee, the ankle and of the Galactic-to-extragalactic transition. It could also be used to veto the cosmic ray background in gamma-ray observations. This technique provides a possibility for up to two orders of magnitude improvement of sensitivity for gamma-ray flux in the energy band above 10 PeV, compared to KASCADE-Grande, and an order-of-magnitude improvement of sensitivity in the multi-EeV energy band, compared to Pierre Auger Observatory.

In the discussion:

> We have shown that observations of strongly inclined
>   EAS with a system of wide FoV IACTs overlooking the
>   horizon strip could be used to characterise the muon and
>   electron content of the EAS and in this way to determine
>   the  identity  of  the  primary  high-energy  particle  which initiated it.

So it seems a complicated field dependent a lot on modelling.

Now to the specific questions:

> why are there showers initiated by photons that contain a muon,
>    what is the process taking place for an electron/positron cascade to produce muons?

The original photon interaction cascades into hadrons by positron annihilations and electron scatterings on atoms on its way to the ground , both for photons and protons, but the specifics have to be modelled.

> When do these muons stop, when they decay after their ~μs lifetimes or due to bremsstrahlung on the ground?

High energy muons will scatter weakly with the ground and penetrate to some depth depending on the energy,  loosing energy by electromagnetic interactions but because of their mass they are quite penetrating. [See this article.](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-01277-3)

When their energy is degraded enough, they decay.

Comment: It sounds a possible answer although I cannot trust an answer coming from a paper analyzing gamma-ray showers _before_ the first very high energy gamma-ray source was discovered (1989, Crab Nebula by the Whipple telescope). "Found to be only marginally less than un cosmic-ray initiated showers" -> this is not true according to the presentation I copied above. Please I need an answer from somebody who knows it, not guess it.

Comment: Edit the answer quoting a paper where they discuss how to distinguish hadron from gamma-ray initiated showers by their muon content (because gamma-ray ones do usually _not_ have muons in them) does not help. I was serious about please letting this to be answered by somebody who knows the answer and not randomly searches for papers on the internet